# Getting Facebook picture info or ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload

I am creating a facebook app in which I change the User Display picture.Now if the user again come to my app i want to see that either he is an old user or a new one.
What my algo is to rename the picture like that `PictureName-Old**`,Later if I find word like `Old**` in user display picture then I realize that he is an old User.

**problem:**
Facebook changes the name of your image once it get uploaded,it becomes like this

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/553951_4dsdfs422_793586546_n.jpg
```

Is there anyway to restore the name? Or is there any way that I can get that the User was old or New?

EDIT: I dont want to use SQL or File handling. I know these are the solutions but I want to make light weight app
Thanks

Comment: No, i don't think so, actually there are also many loopholes, how do you know if user came 5 times in 5 mints, i think you should save entry in the database with the time or set a status in the database to see old or new entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the filename is changed by Facebook, there isn't a way to "save" that information there.

You'll have to save your users' uids somewhere.

Comment: What about storing info inside the photo caption or somewhere??

Comment: That could be easily removed or changed by the user. You could create a new album with a 'special' name, and then check if that album exists, but it is an ugly hack - and again, the user could remove/rename it. Unreliable.